# How to troubleshoot a "long running script" message in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Internet Explorer 11 displays the message at the bottom that a `not responding due to long running script`.  And it's true - the browser is pretty much unresponsive for a while.

I've inherited a code base with 30-40 js includes and they are all doing all kinds of things.

How do I find out specifically which script is causing this problem?
How do I troubleshoot this type of problem in general?

Comment: The network tab (in the browsers debug window) should tell you what request is long running, then just search for that URL in your code base

Comment: If it's locking the UI someone will of set async false on an ajax request, look for `async:false` for jquery or an `XMLHTTPRequest` where the third parameter is `false`. Then read [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) to fix it

Comment: @Liam It's definitely not a network request that's causing the problem.  There is nothing in the Network tab.

Comment: @AngryHacker did you find solution?

Comment: Any one found any solutions to this issue?